# Convert JSON array into CSV

Tags: csv, json, jq

I'm looking at solutions to convert JSON to a CSV. It seems most of the solutions expect the JSON to be a single object rather than an array of objects.

All the solutions I've tried from here seem to break with my input, which comes from [curling this site](https://pressbooks.online.ucf.edu/wp-json/pressbooks/v2/books/).

How can I convert the JSON into a CSV with `jq` or another tool when the input is an array instead of an object.

```
[
  {
    "id": "4",
    "link": "https://pressbooks.online.ucf.edu/amnatgov/",
    "metadata": {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "Book",
      "name": "American Government",
      "inLanguage": "en",
      "copyrightYear": "2016",
      "disambiguatingDescription": "The content of this textbook has been developed and arranged to provide a logical progression from the fundamental principles of institutional design at the founding, to avenues of political participation, to thorough coverage of the political structures that constitute American government. The book builds upon what students have already learned and emphasizes connections between topics as well as between theory and applications. The goal of each section is to enable students not just to recognize concepts, but to work with them in ways that will be useful in later courses, future careers, and as engaged citizens. ",
      "image": "https://pressbooks.online.ucf.edu/app/uploads/sites/4/2020/01/American-Government.png",
      "isBasedOn": "https://ucf-dev.pb.unizin.org/pos2041",
      "author": [
        {
          "@type": "Person",
          "name": "OpenStax"
        }
      ],
      "datePublished": "2016-01-06",
      "copyrightHolder": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "cnxamgov"
      },
      "license": {
        "@type": "CreativeWork",
        "url": "https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/",
        "name": "CC BY (Attribution)"
      }
    },
    "_links": {
      "api": [
        {
          "href": "https://pressbooks.online.ucf.edu/amnatgov/wp-json/"
        }
      ],
      "metadata": [
        {
          "href": "https://pressbooks.online.ucf.edu/amnatgov/wp-json/pressbooks/v2/metadata"
        }
      ],
      "self": [
        {
          "href": "https://pressbooks.online.ucf.edu/wp-json/pressbooks/v2/books/4"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Desired Format:

```
id, link, context, type, name, inLanguage, image, author_type, author_name, license_type, license_url, license_name
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @jesse_b a CSV with each value with metadata flattened (so that name, copyright, ect, are all csv rows).

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride, considering your multi-leveled input structure, it would be better if you posted the expected csv output - adding it to your question

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest added

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride "author" is an array. How would you like to handle multiple authors?

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda, I think converting it to a string separated by some value like ; would work

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride See update to my answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The issue is not really that the JSON that you show is an array, but that each element of the array (of which you only have one) is a fairly complex structure.  It is straight forward to extract the relevant data from each array entry into a shorter flat array and convert that into CSV with `@csv` in `jq`:

```
jq -r '.[] | [
        .id,
        .link,
        .metadata."@context",
        .metadata."@type",
        .metadata.name,
        .metadata.inLanguage,
        .metadata.image,
        .metadata.author[0]."@type",
        .metadata.author[0].name,
        .metadata.license."@type",
        .metadata.license.url,
        .metadata.license.name
] | @csv' file.json
```

... but notice how I'm forced to decide that we're only ever interested in the first author (the `.metadata.author` sub-structure is an array).

The output:

```
"4","https://pressbooks.online.ucf.edu/amnatgov/","http://schema.org","Book","American Government","en","https://pressbooks.online.ucf.edu/app/uploads/sites/4/2020/01/American-Government.png","Person","OpenStax","CreativeWork","https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/","CC BY (Attribution)"
```

---

To create author name strings that are concatenations of all author names (and similarly for author types), with `;` as delimiter, you could instead of `.metadata.author[0].name` in the above use `[.metadata.author[].name]|join(";")` (and  `[.metadata.author[]."@type"]|join(";")` for the type), so that your command becomes

```
jq -r '.[] | [
        .id,
        .link,
        .metadata."@context",
        .metadata."@type",
        .metadata.name,
        .metadata.inLanguage,
        .metadata.image,
        ( [ .metadata.author[]."@type" ] | join(";") ),
        ( [ .metadata.author[].name    ] | join(";") ),
        .metadata.license."@type",
        .metadata.license.url,
        .metadata.license.name
] | @csv' file.json
```

Comment: This is most elegant pure jq solution I've seen for generating CSV in bash, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Majky Note that this has nothing whatsoever to do with `bash` or any other shell.  :-)  But thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) you can "flat" the JSON, running

```
mlr --j2c cat input.json >output.csv
```

```
+----+---------------------------------------------+-------------------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | link                                        | metadata:@context | metadata:@type | metadata:name       | metadata:inLanguage | metadata:copyrightYear | metadata:disambiguatingDescription                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             | metadata:image                                                                        | metadata:isBasedOn                    | metadata:author:0:@type | metadata:author:0:name | metadata:datePublished | metadata:copyrightHolder:@type | metadata:copyrightHolder:name | metadata:license:@type | metadata:license:url                         | metadata:license:name | _links:api:0:href                                   | _links:metadata:0:href                                                    | _links:self:0:href                                              |
+----+---------------------------------------------+-------------------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| 4  | https://pressbooks.online.ucf.edu/amnatgov/ | http://schema.org | Book           | American Government | en                  | 2016                   | The content of this textbook has been developed and arranged to provide a logical progression from the fundamental principles of institutional design at the founding, to avenues of political participation, to thorough coverage of the political structures that constitute American government. The book builds upon what students have already learned and emphasizes connections between topics as well as between theory and applications. The goal of each section is to enable students not just to recognize concepts, but to work with them in ways that will be useful in later courses, future careers, and as engaged citizens.  | https://pressbooks.online.ucf.edu/app/uploads/sites/4/2020/01/American-Government.png | https://ucf-dev.pb.unizin.org/pos2041 | Person                  | OpenStax               | 2016-01-06             | Organization                   | cnxamgov                      | CreativeWork           | https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/ | CC BY (Attribution)   | https://pressbooks.online.ucf.edu/amnatgov/wp-json/ | https://pressbooks.online.ucf.edu/amnatgov/wp-json/pressbooks/v2/metadata | https://pressbooks.online.ucf.edu/wp-json/pressbooks/v2/books/4 |
+----+---------------------------------------------+-------------------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and then extract the fields you want and renaming them using

```
mlr -I --csv cut -f "id","link","metadata:@context","metadata:@type","metadata:name","metadata:inLanguage","metadata:image","metadata:author:0:@type","metadata:author:0:name","metadata:license:@type","metadata:license:url","metadata:license:name" \
then label id,link,context,type,name,inLanguage,image,author_type,author_name,license_type,license_url,license_name output.csv
```

The output will be

```
+----+---------------------------------------------+-------------------+------+---------------------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+----------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| id | link                                        | context           | type | name                | inLanguage | image                                                                                 | author_type | author_name | license_type | license_url                                  | license_name        |
+----+---------------------------------------------+-------------------+------+---------------------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+----------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| 4  | https://pressbooks.online.ucf.edu/amnatgov/ | http://schema.org | Book | American Government | en         | https://pressbooks.online.ucf.edu/app/uploads/sites/4/2020/01/American-Government.png | Person      | OpenStax    | CreativeWork | https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/ | CC BY (Attribution) |
+----+---------------------------------------------+-------------------+------+---------------------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+----------------------------------------------+---------------------+
```